# Auto generate sitemap in wordpress

Tags: sitemap

Is there any code to Auto generate sitemaps in wordpress custom theme.
I have a blog site built in wordpress and have manually created sitemap for each page.

*I am not using plugins because*

*1.I do not require all pages to be listed  in sitemap*

*2.Additional Plugins will increase load time in my site*

Now i need a simple method(code) to generate a sitemap of my blogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple code which you need to add in your theme function file to generate sitemap when each blog is posted.Please refer this [blog](https://wordpress-trickz.blogspot.com/2020/01/auto-update-sitemap-in-wordpress.html) 
This can also be used in any custom plugins.

```php
add_action("publish_post", "eg_create_sitemap");

add_action( "save_post", "eg_create_sitemap" );  

function eg_create_sitemap() {

    $postsForSitemap = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'orderby'     => 'modified',
        'post_type'   => array( 'post'),
        'order'       => 'DESC'
    ) );
    $sitemap = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    $sitemap .= "\n" . '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">' . "\n";    
    foreach( $postsForSitemap as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post );   
        $postdate = explode( " ", $post->post_modified );   
        $sitemap .= "\t" . '<url>' . "\n" .
            "\t\t" . '<loc>' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '</loc>' .
            "\n\t\t" . '<lastmod>' . $postdate[0] . '</lastmod>' .
            "\n\t\t" . '<changefreq>monthly</changefreq>' .
            "\n\t" . '</url>' . "\n";
    }     
    $sitemap .= '</urlset>';     
    $fp = fopen( ABSPATH . "sitemap_blog.xml", 'w' );
    fwrite( $fp, $sitemap );
    fclose( $fp );

}
```

Comment: I have added this code but it is showing error

Comment: @PrismDevelopmentTeamgroupe please can you share a screenshot of the error.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/qo0rpl

Comment: This is some syntax error in your funciton file.